# Homomorphic encryption scheme for modulo reduction

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, modular-arithmetic

I want to know if there is any Homomorphic encryption scheme that supports modulo reduction, i.e.,
using $Enc_{pk}(m)$ and a public $w$ to compute $Enc_{pk}(m \mod w)$.

Thank you.

Comment: Although your problem is simpler, [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/70449/homomorphic-modulo) may be useful, as it asks about homomorphic modular reduction involving two ciphertexts.